# wipe exchange folder to specified size

Tags: python, exchangelib

I am trying to delete messages in an Exchange folder until the folder size reaches a specified value in bytes.

Here is my example code:

```
def get_foldersize(folder):
    if folder.__class__ != folders.Messages:
        return -1
    return sum(folder.all().values_list('size', flat=True))


def wipe_by_size(folder=account.inbox, size='4.8gb', result_as_str=True):
    """
    Delete all old messages in specified exchange folder to specified size
    size may setted like str ("4,9gb", "500.5 Mb", "1024kB") or like int (means size setted in bytes)
    if result_as_str == True, func returns a stats delete msg, 
    otherwise tuple (deleted_files_count, deleted_bytes, before_files_count, before_bytes, after_files_count, after_bytes)
    """
    if folder.__class__ != folders.Messages:
        raise ValueError("Param 'folder' not a exchange-server folder object!")

    m = {
        'gb': 1024 ** 3,
        'mb': 1024 ** 2,
        'kb': 1024,
    }

    size_bytes = None

    if isinstance(size, str):
        if ',' in size:
            size = size.replace(',', '.')

        for k, v in m.items():
            if k in size.lower():
                size = size.split(k)[0].strip()
                try:
                    size_float = float(size)
                    size_bytes = round(size_float * v)
                except ValueError:
                    raise ValueError(f"Incorrect format of param 'size', recieve '{size_str}'")
                break
        else:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Incorrect format of 'size' param, '{size_str}' must contains int or float number and something from '{list(m.keys())}'")
    elif isinstance(size, (int, float,)):
        size_bytes = int(size)
    else:
        raise ValueError(
            'Parameter "size" can be a str (example:"4,9gb", "500.5 Mb", "1024kB") or int folder size in bytes')

    if get_foldersize(folder) < size_bytes:
        return

    before = folder.total_count
    before_bytes = get_foldersize(folder)

    while get_foldersize(folder) > size_bytes:
        msg = folder.all().order_by('datetime_received')[0]
        try:
            # print(msg.subject, msg.sender)
            msg.delete()
        except Exception as e:
            if msg is not None:
                print(f"wipe_by_size: Can't delete {msg.sender}({msg.subject})")
            else:
                print("wipe_by_size: msg = None")

    after = folder.total_count
    deleted = before - after

    after_bytes = get_foldersize(folder)
    deleted_bytes = before_bytes - after_bytes

    if result_as_str:
        return f"""Wiped {deleted} file(s), freed {'{0:12,d}'.format(
            deleted_bytes)} bytes. Before: {before} files, {'{0:12,d}'.format(
            before_bytes)} bytes. After: {after} files, {'{0:12,d}'.format(after_bytes)} bytes"""

    return deleted, deleted_bytes, before, before_bytes, after, after_bytes


delete_msg = wipe_by_size(folder=account.sent, size='4,8gb')
deleted, deleted_bytes, before, before_bytes, after, after_bytes = wipe_by_size(folder=account.sent, size='4,8gb')
```

The function works but very slowly - 
slowly because `get_foldersize()` is called for each iteration of the while-loop.

I suggest I need to get all messages in the folder in reverse order(like now), store the size of each message, then calculate how many and which messages I need to wipe and delete them all in one go. I think that will more faster. But I don't know how (and if it's possible?) to get the message size.

Comment: In the future, try to limit your code to the smallest possible example that still shows the error. There are some tips at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message size is contained in the `size` field, as you found out. So you could calculate the folder size once, and then read `msg.size` and decrement the total folder size in a loop. Finally, reduce network traffic by only getting the `size` field of each message in the folder:

```
class FolderSize(ExtendedProperty):
    property_tag = 0x0e08
    property_type = 'Integer'

Folder.register('size', FolderSize)

folder = account.inbox
folder_size = folder.size
max_size = 123456789  # Bytes

for msg in folder.all().only('size'):
    if folder_size <= max_size:
        break
    msg.delete()
    folder_size -= msg.size
```

Comment: thank you very much! ) can you help with check of folders instance in get_foldersize()? because if folder.__class__ != folders.Messages: didn't pass an acount.sent folder :/

Comment: In that case, I would suggest fetching the size of the folder directly, using extended properties. I have updated the example above (the `FolderSize` part comes from the exchangelib README).

Comment: sorry, Erik, but i'am afraid folder.size returns size of all letters but without attachments of each letter :/ because i get a much more different values from folder.size and in Outlook interface at folder properties, folder size window.. Outlook reports 4945451 KB but folder.size is about 70Mb.. i have folder with many letters each one has at least one attachment of 2-20Mb.. can you help?.. i try to register PidTagAttachSize Canonical Property at Message but unsuccessfull :/ thank you!

Comment: In that case, I would just sum the individual message sizes to get the true folder size: `sum(folder.all().values_list('size', flat=True))`.